# PVS studio compare with sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube, pvs-studio

I recently came across PVS Studio. I would like to know how PVS Studio is different from SonarQube. I see that, both tools perform static code analysis. I am trying to understand which is the best tool to opt for.

Any insights are helpful.

Best Regards
Gowtham

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean by SonarQube? As SonarQube itself is a continuous quality assurance platform, and PVS-Studio is a set of static analyzers for C/C++/C#, the direct comparison would be improper. You can actually integrate PVS-Studio into SonarQube. I can assume that you are asking for a comparison between PVS-Studio and some of other analyzers that SonarQube supports, but which ones exactly?

Comment: In my understanding, sonarqube does the similar analysis what PVS-studio does. I would like to know if I am using sonarqube, do I need to use PVS-studio further? I am trying to understand the advantages I would get if I use PVS-Studio along with sonarqube. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will certainly get additional advantage when using PVS-Studio together with SonarQube. We do not have a direct comparison between the analyzers, but you can look at this article: "[Analysis of PascalABC.NET using SonarQube plugins: SonarC# and PVS-Studio](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0492/)". The thing is, SonarQube is a code quality assurance platform, and it is not primarily orientated at finding errors. In general, it looks for "code smells". For example, a file does not start with a comment block. This is not an error in itself. PVS-Studio is orientated toward finding the 'direct' errors.

Comment: Thank you Paul. This is very helpful analysis.